# How many seconds from mysql time format to now

Tags: php, datetime, date, comparison

I use this function to set a time `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+2 minutes")`. Now I want to compare that value with the current time to find the amount of seconds it's left.

For example compare: `$next_action = 2011-01-16 18:03:00` and `$now = 2011-01-16 18:01:23`. To find the amount of seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strtotime can convert mysql timestamps to unix timestamps. so you just convert both of them to UNIX timestamps and subtract one from other, and you'll get the difference in seconds.

```
$next_action = "2011-01-16 18:03:00";
$now = "2011-01-16 18:01:23";

echo strtotime($next_action)-strtotime($now);
```

Why did you convert them to "Y-m-d H:i:s" in the first place?  Unix timestamps are much easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

```
$start_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+2 minutes"));
$time_diff = (time() - strtotime($start_time)); // difference in seconds

$seconds = $time_diff % 60;
$minutes = ($time_diff - $seconds) % (60 * 60);
$hours = ($time_diff - ($minutes * 60) - $seconds) / (24 * 60 * 60);
```

Untested, but it would probably go something like this.